# Strange CSP error in Firefox

Tags: firefox, content-security-policy

I recently added the following CSP policies for https://stefan.sofa-rockers.org/

```
default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://brick.a.ssl.fastly.net; font-src 'self' https://brick.a.ssl.fastly.net
```

It seems to work well on all browser, but Firefox is showing me this strange, truncated error message:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src https://stefan.sofa-rockers.org”). Source: (function (ERROR) {

    const V8_STACK_.... stefan.sofa-rockers.org:1
```

Do I have an error in my CSP (all resources are getting loaded, so I don't think this is the case) or might this be a bug in Firefox itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may be hitting a known Firefox bug that’s been partially fixed in Firefox 58. See the *Improved Content Security Policy (CSP) Handling* section of the following blog post:

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2017/11/20/extensions-in-firefox-58/

The relevant existing Firefox bugs are these:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1406278
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267027

And specifically, as noted in the comments here, if you have the Privacy Badger add-on installed, you might need to consider disabling it.

See also the following related Stack Overflow answers:

- [Firefox content script not loading in some pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622435/firefox-content-script-not-loading-in-some-pages/47705529#47705529)
- [Content Security Policy failing on line 1 (Firefox 57.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519661/content-security-policy-failing-on-line-1-firefox-57-0/47553747#47553747)

Comment: Privacy Badger was the culprit.  Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: I also had this error, cause by Privacy Badger. Oddly, it happened even if I set "Turn off Privacy Badger For This Site".  I had to completely disable the add-on to fix the problem.