# nginx CSP not allowing explicitly permitted google analytics script

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

I am stuck. I can't get the google analytics (and other external scripts for that matter) running.

Here's what I did in nginx:

```
server {
  # other stuff
  location = /mylocation {
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.google-analytics.com";      
  }
}
```

I've attached a screenshot to show that this header information is actually received by the browser (i.e. in this case it's Firefox).

So the script should be executed but it isn't.

In the Console I am getting (translated from German the actual English error message will propably be different):

"Content Security Policy: the settings of the page have blocked loading of a resource on https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js ("script-src")"

What's wrong with my policy settings?

Answer (score 0):

So after banging my head against the wall for hours and even telling my customer that I manufactured a broken functionality it turns out the problem was an add-on I had installed on my dev machine's firefox. Finally found the solution here:

[Strange CSP error in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720227/strange-csp-error-in-firefox?answertab=active#tab-top)